# Python 3.6.9 . ImportError: No module named setuptools_rust and a Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, setuptools, pyopenssl

I am trying to install pyOpenSSl and it shows the following error

> Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /home/tony/hx-preinstaller-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL)
> Collecting cryptography>=3.3 (from pyOpenSSL)
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/98/8a258ab4787e6f835d350639792527d2eb7946ff9fc0caca9c3f4cf5dcfe/cryptography-3.4.8.tar.gz
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================
        If you are seeing an error here please try the following to
        successfully install cryptography:

        Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
        users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-8toyhikv/cryptography/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    from setuptools_rust import RustExtension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
```

The command I ran:

```
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try upgrade pip and install setuptools-rust:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install setuptools-rust
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried upgrading pip itself first?

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this command if you are on linux 
for **python3**

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

for **python2**

```
python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue while using 'scrapy' and following command fixed everything for me:

```
python3 -m pip install scrapy --upgrade --force --user
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the pip this way worked for me:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing setuptools_rust first:

```
pip install setuptools_rust
```

And then installing pyOpenSSL again